# Understanding static variables declaration/initialization in C

Tags: c, static, linkage

I have only one file in my project called test.c; the code below does not compile if I do not define "TRUE". I use vc. I just want to understand the behavior. Please throw some light on this aspect.

```
#ifdef TRUE
static int a; 
static int a = 1; 
#else 
static int a = 1; 
static int a; 
#endif 

int main (void) 
{ 
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0; 
}
-----------------------
#ifdef TRUE     // both ok
int a; 
int a = 1; 
#else           // both ok
int a = 1; 
int a; 
#endif

int main (void) 
{ 
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Try including the error message. We are not clairvoyant.

Comment: actually pasting the exact error message into your question is generally what you should be doing.

Comment: 'a' redefinition; different storage class

Answer (score 8):

That is because you can not declare a variable after you have defined it. However you may define a variable after you declare it.

```
#ifdef TRUE
static int a; //Declaring variable a
static int a = 1; //define variable a
#else 
static int a = 1; //define variable a
static int a; //Error! a is already defined so you can not declare it
#endif
```

Comment: Well technically, you _may_ define it after you declare it. :P But +1.

Comment: +1 for your comment, I was seeing variable and thinking struct.

Answer (score -3):

Apparently, the compiler does not let you redefine a variable that has been initialized..

Comment: you get in hells kitchen if you allow mulitple defines of the same.