# static variable in vc

Tags: c, static, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding static variables declaration/initialization in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417478/understanding-static-variables-declaration-initialization-in-c)

I have only one file in my project called test.c; the code below does not compile if I do not define "TRUE". I use vc, the error is:'a' redefinition, different storage class. I just want to understand the behavior. Please throw some light on this aspect.

```
#ifdef TRUE 
static int a;  
static int a = 1;  
#else  
static int a = 1;  
static int a;  
#endif  

int main (void)  
{  
    printf("%d\n", a); 
    return 0;  
}
```

When I omit the 'static':

```
#ifdef TRUE 
int a;  
int a = 1;  
#else  
int a = 1;  
int a;  
#endif
```

both of them are ok.

Comment: @caisp: if you need clarifications on an answer you should ask them in a comment to it instead of opening a new identical question!

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
#ifdef TRUE 
static int a = 1;  
#else  
static int a = 1;  
#endif
```

Comment: Look it up in your text book declarations

Comment: I think that the problem here is understanding why with `static` it's not possible to re-declare after defining while with non-static variables it's possible.

Comment: In gcc, both of them are ok. `static int a;`constitutes a `tentative definition`